# How to pass a function through parameters using generics

Tags: java, collections, functional-interface

Given the following code:

```
static <U,V> List<V> map(Iterable<U> l, Function<U,V> f) {
    return null;
}
```

I need to pass an `arraylist` in the first parameter and a hash function in the second which takes a string and outputs a type int.

I'm trying the following but get the following error message.

```
map(names,<String,Integer> hashCode());

map(names,hash());
```

> Error message:Not applicable for the arguments int

Need to pass a hash function so I can use this function inside the method.

Comment: `map(names, name -> name.hashCode())`?

Comment: `map(names, String::hashCode)`

Comment: Any feedback on the comments or answer you received here?

Answer (score 0):

Here:

```
hashCode()
```

isn't a **function**! It is simply a method invocation. You would rather need a lambda, something like:

```
x -> x.hashCode()
```

or, as you are probably using the hashcode of the current object:

```
this::hashCode
```

But that actually depends on the object on which you intend to invoke the hashCode method. And of course, there is also difference regarding the interface you intend to "use", be it a [Function](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Function.html) or [Supplier](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Supplier.html) (that second method reference example would be a supplier for example).

Comment: `this::hashCode` would be a Supplier, not a Function.

Comment: @shmosel Good observation, I updated the answer accordingly.

Comment: I don’t get why you insist on suggesting `this::hashCode`. The OP showed a reasonable method declaration like `map(Iterable<U> l, Function<U,V> f)` and even continued with the matching explanation “… and a hash function in the second which takes a string and outputs a type int”, clearly indicating that your first lambda expression, `x -> x.hashCode()`, or an equivalent `Object::hashCode` (or `String::hashCode`, to match the task literally), is the right way to go.